# Two different audio file playing on Left channel and right channel with pygame

Tags: python, audio, pygame, mixer

I have a code where I specified two different audio files in two different channels and plays simultaneously, but I need a way to make each file play on only one channel and the other on the other channel. For instance, two audio files playing simultaneously on two seperate channels, Right and Left. Such that an audio plays on right speaker and the other audio plays on left speaker.

I tried with the code below, but the audio is not mapping to any specific channel but are playing on both speakers.

```
pygame.mixer.init(frequency=44000, size=-16,channels=2, buffer=4096)
#pygame.mixer.set_num_channels(2)
m = pygame.mixer.Sound('tone.wav')
n = pygame.mixer.Sound('sound.wav')
pygame.mixer.Channel(1).play(m,-1)
pygame.mixer.Channel(2).play(n,-1)
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Are the channels zero indexed? You might need `Channel(0)` and `Channel(1)`.

Comment: I did not understand?

Comment: pygame.mixer.Channel(0).play(m,-1)
pygame.mixer.Channel(1).play(n,-1)   Gave same results.

Comment: [The docs](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Channel.set_volume) say you have to pass the volume of the left and right channel, e.g.: `channel1.play(sound1)`, `channel1.set_volume(1.0, 0.0)` to turn off the right speaker, but that doesn't work for me. It works correctly if I pass only one number. Maybe it's a bug.

Comment: @skrx Thanks! this actually seems the answer to my question.

Comment: Does it work for you?

Comment: Yes, it is working.

Comment: Please move the solution to the answer, so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs say that you have to pass the volume of the left and right speaker to [`Channel.set_volume`](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mixer.html#pygame.mixer.Channel.set_volume).

```
# Create Sound and Channel instances.
sound0 = pg.mixer.Sound('my_sound.wav')
channel0 = pg.mixer.Channel(0)

# Play the sound (that will reset the volume to the default).
channel0.play(sound0)
# Now change the volume of the specific speakers.
# The first argument is the volume of the left speaker and
# the second argument is the volume of the right speaker.
channel0.set_volume(1.0, 0.0)
```

---

Also, if you don't want to manage the channels yourself, you can just use the channel that `Sound.play()` returns.

```
channel = sound0.play()
channel.set_volume(1.0, 0.0)
```